# Default image if no record with image path on database

Tags: php, database, image, src

I want to show a default image if there isn't any record on the table of images. I am using this one, but it shows nothing when the db's table is empty.

```
<img class="image--cover" id="blah" src="<?php echo $row2['img_local']; ?>" alt="Avatar" title="DEFINIDA" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='1.png';">
```

Actually, it doesn't even shows some broken image icon, not even the allocated space for this element. Any thoughts?

Edit: this is the "upload.php" code that i am using to upload the images

```
    <?php
session_start();
    include('includes/conexao.php');
    $fileinfo=PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $newFilename=$fileinfo['filename'] ."_". time() . "." . $fileinfo['extension'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/perfis/" . $newFilename);
    $location="images/perfis/" . $newFilename;


$todas_fotos = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * FROM esc_usuarios_fotos WHERE img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'");

if( mysqli_num_rows($todas_fotos) > 0) {
        //$path=$location;
        //if(unlink($path)) echo "Deleted file ";
        mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE esc_usuarios_fotos SET img_local = '$location' WHERE img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'");
}
else
{
        mysqli_query($conexao,"insert into esc_usuarios_fotos (img_local, img_usu_codigo) values ('$location', '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "')");
};


    header('location:perfil.php');
?>
```

Comment: did you check your style.? style may affect the element.!

Comment: Can you show what's echoed in `<?php echo $row2['img_local']; ?>`

Comment: i have updated the details

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<img class="image--cover" id="blah" src="<?php if(!empty($row2['img_local'])){ echo $row2['img_local'];}else{ echo '1.png';} ?>" alt="Avatar" title="DEFINIDA" >
```

Also check path of 1.png.. Like images/1.png or img/1.png etc..

Comment: Still, nothing is loaded

Comment: do you check path of 1.png ? is it in root folder or in any subfolder ? also is it class="image--cover" or class="image-cover" ? if 1.png is in images folder, then it should be src="<?php if(!empty($row2['img_local'])){ echo $row2['img_local'];}else{ echo 'images/1.png';} ?>"

Comment: the path is correct, but i got no changes at all trying different paths

Comment: Nothing, it's so weird, looks like there is no difference between a wrong and correct path

Answer (score 0):

we can try 
set by-default value to database column img_local (Ex. default.png) , so if user not change  image or there is no insert image in database it's remain default.png ,if user change it  become user.png , if user remove image it's again update to default.png

Comment: Newbie here, how to go?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT 'images/default.png'`.    then add default.png in your images folder

Comment: But if the user removes the image, nothing is shown, cause in your code, there must be at least one record to show default.png, waht I want is to show a image if there is nothing on database

Comment: when user click 'remove image' button , dont delete it , instead of delete query execute update query , and set again to  'images/default.png' as a value to column

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below logic:

```
<?php
$row2['img_local'] = 'DB_data_folder_Path_to_image_with_image_name.extension';
// You do not have to use above line.

if ((!empty($row2['img_local'])) && (file_exists($row2['img_local']))) {
    echo '<img class="image--cover" id="blah" src="'.$row2['img_local'].'" alt="Avatar" title="DEFINIDA" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=1.png;">';
} else {
    echo 'Show a default image.'; // <img src="path_to_default_image" alt="Default_image"/>
}
?>
```

Comment: Nothing yet, i'm losting hope

Comment: You have set `"images/perfis/" . $newFilename` in DB. So on trying to display it, you have to specify the full path. Can you add the path on which you are seeing this page in browser or the folder structure

Answer (score 0):

My friend,

If you get this from HTML perspective... and put that image in one DIV,  your [onerror="";] could work better.

like this example:

```
<div id="myContainerImg">
    <img class="image--cover" id="blah" src="<?php echo $row2['img_local']; ?>" alt="Avatar" title="DEFINIDA" onerror="putNoImage();">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function putNoImage(){
    document.getElementById('myContainerImg').innerHTML = 'no image here, or put your own img...';
  }
</script>
```

And, you can see it running [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Yamamila/pen/NLdgWw?editors=1010).